# Парсинг json с помощью Php

Tags: php, json

Нужно распарсить данный очень интересный файлик [тык](https://epulze.com/api/t/tournaments?page=1&limit=15&offset=0&sorting=start:asc&state=1,4,2&gameMode=1021,21&serverRegion=3&games=dota2)
Делал вот так:
Пытался сделать вывод строк "id" и "name"из каждого массива и записывать их в базу данных
Записывает только последнюю строку из массива
Подскажите как сделать записи всех строк в базу
P.s. я начинающий не судите строго и заранее спасибо

```
$url = 'https://epulze.com/api/t/tournaments?page=1&limit=15&offset=0&sorting=start:asc&state=1,4,2&gameMode=1021,21&serverRegion=3&games=dota2';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
$trans = json_decode($file, true);
foreach ($trans["data"] as $test1){  
   var_dump ($test1["name"]);
}
$info = R::dispense('dbtest'); 
if(!empty($trans["name"])) $info->name = trim(strip_tags($trans["name"]));
R::store($info);
```

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, пожалуйста. Добавил фигурные скобки к блоку if и занес его в цикл:

```
$url = 'https://epulze.com/api/t/tournaments?page=1&limit=15&offset=0&sorting=start:asc&state=1,4,2&gameMode=1021,21&serverRegion=3&games=dota2';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
$trans = json_decode($file, true);
foreach ($trans["data"] as $test1) {
    var_dump($test1["name"]);
    
    $info = R::dispense('dbtest');
    if (!empty($trans["name"])) {
        $info->name = trim(strip_tags($trans["name"]));
        R::store($info);
    }
}
```

Если указанный Вами код записывает только последнюю строку из массива, то этот запишет все.